# Sorting MultiButtonList or ComponentGroup

Tags: sorting, codenameone

Is there any way to sort a [multibuttonlist](/questions/tagged/multibuttonlist) or a [componentgroup](/questions/tagged/componentgroup) by TextLine1 or TextLine2?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a sort algorithm as you normally would.

To sort the multi buttons just remove them and add them based on that order (assuming you are using a layout manager such as box layout). You can also animated them into place using animateLayout if you want that.

Comment: so these classes do not provide methods for sorting?

Comment: They are strictly visual so no.